# UITableView throws EXC_BAD_ACCESS when using custom UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, exc-bad-access

I am trying to build a contact table using custom UITableViewCell, but every time I try load the view, I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.

The code for my Table is as follows:

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    if(indexPath.section == 0){
        NSString *ilabel = [[[contactDetails objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *itext = [[[contactDetails objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:1];

        CustomCell *cell= [[[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        // Default to no selected style and not selected
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        [cell setCellData:ilabel textVal:itext];


        return cell;

        [ilabel release];
        [itext release];
    }

}
```

with my cell class:

```
@implementation CustomCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {

    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code.
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setCellData:(NSString *)ilabel textVal:(NSString *)itext {
    _label.text = ilabel;
    _text.text = itext;

    // Alloc and set the frame
    _label.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 286, 68);

    // Add subview
    [self.contentView addSubview:_label];  
}


- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {

    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state.
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Any help will be appreciated as I am completely stumped.

Comment: Are you sure that `NSString *itext = [[[contactDetails objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:1];
` works all the time? And by the way, enable `NSZombieEnabled` for your executable and look at the console again, this should give you a better hint on what went wrong.

Comment: May be the reason is that contactDetails is nil ???

Comment: Dont forget to accept answers ...

Answer (score 1):

Remove

```
[ilabel release];
[itext release];
```

Because they are auto released Objects.

Answer (score 1):

Initial thoughts:

1. You should dequeue a cell in an attempt to reuse cell's in memory (but that are off screen). Please reference the [UITableView documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html), particularly `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`.
2. The two release lines, `[ilabel release];` and `[itext release];` will never be called because they are below the `return cell;` line: the method ceases executing at that point.
3. I am assuming you are inheriting from UITableViewCell with your CustomCell class, correct? I find it odd that you are treating it differently than other UITableViewCell examples I have worked with and you didn't post your header file so I could confirm.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    if(indexPath.section == 0){
        NSString *ilabel = [[[contactDetails objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *itext = [[[contactDetails objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:1];

        CustomCell *cell= [[[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        // Default to no selected style and not selected
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        [cell setCellData:ilabel textVal:itext];


        return cell;

        [ilabel release];
        [itext release];
    }
```

The code here is not correct because you cant writr

```
[ilabel release];
[itext release];
```

after `return cell;`, because that part of code will never called !!!

Comment: Yeah that is right....and @Hannes could you tell me how many sections you  are having?

Answer (score 0):

Here is custom cell example ...

.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#define TAGS_TITLE_SIZE     20.0f
#define TITLE_LABEL_TAG     1
#define DATA_TIME_LABEL_TAG 5
#define ARROW_IMAGE_TAG     6
#define MAIN_IMAGE_TAG      7
#define TITLE_START_POSS    34

// Enumeration for initiakization TableView Cells
typedef enum {
    NONE_TABLE_CELL                = 0,
    TAGS_TABLE_CELL_WITHOUT_SWITCH = 1,
    TAGS_TABLE_CELL_WITH_SWITCH    = 2
}TableTypeEnumeration;

@protocol SwitchDelegate
- (void)valueChangeNotify:(id)sender;
- (void)trashClickedNotify:(id)sender;
@end

// Class for Custom Table View Cell.
@interface CustomTableViewCell : UITableViewCell {
    // Title of the cell.
    UILabel*  cellTitle;
    UISwitch* cellSwitch;
    UIButton* cellButton; 

    id<SwitchDelegate> delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id <SwitchDelegate> delegate;

// Set the title of the cell.
- (void) SetCellTitle: (NSString*) _cellTitle;
- (void) SetRowIndex: (int) _rowIndex;
- (void) SwitchOnOff: (BOOL) _switchTo;

- (void) InitCellTitleLable;

// Init With Style (With additional parametr TableTypeEnumeration)
- (id)initWithStyle: (UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier: (NSString *)reuseIdentifier tableType:(TableTypeEnumeration)tabletypeEnum;

@end
```

.m file

```
#import "CustomTableViewCell.h"

@implementation CustomTableViewCell

@synthesize delegate;

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//- Initializes a table-view controller to manage a table view of a given style. ----------------- ViTo Code ----//
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    return [self initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier tableType:NONE_TABLE_CELL];
}

- (id)initWithStyle: (UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier: (NSString *)reuseIdentifier tableType:(TableTypeEnumeration)tabletypeEnum {
    // Get Self.
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {

        // Switch table View Cells
        switch(tabletypeEnum) {
            case TAGS_TABLE_CELL_WITH_SWITCH: {

                // Create and initialize Title of Custom Cell.
                cellTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(TITLE_START_POSS, (44 - TAGS_TITLE_SIZE)/2, 260, 21)];
                cellTitle.backgroundColor      = [UIColor clearColor];
                cellTitle.opaque               = NO;
                cellTitle.textColor            = [UIColor blackColor];
                cellTitle.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
                cellTitle.font                 = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:TAGS_TITLE_SIZE];
                cellTitle.textAlignment        = UITextAlignmentLeft;
                // Create and Initialize Switch of Custom Cell.
                cellSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(185 + TITLE_START_POSS, 10, 10, 10 )];
                [cellSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(valueChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
                // Create and Initialize Trash Button of Custom Cell.
                cellButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(1, 7, 32, 32)];
                [cellButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"remove_tag.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [cellButton addTarget:self action:@selector(touchDown:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

                [self.contentView addSubview:cellTitle];
                [self.contentView addSubview:cellSwitch];
                [self.contentView addSubview:cellButton];
                [cellTitle release];
                [cellSwitch release];
                [cellButton release];

                break;
            }
            case TAGS_TABLE_CELL_WITHOUT_SWITCH: {
                // Create and initialize Title of Custom Cell.
                cellTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, (44 - TAGS_TITLE_SIZE)/2, 260, 21)];
                cellTitle.backgroundColor      = [UIColor clearColor];
                cellTitle.opaque               = NO;
                cellTitle.textColor            = [UIColor blackColor];
                cellTitle.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
                cellTitle.font                 = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:TAGS_TITLE_SIZE];
                cellTitle.textAlignment        = UITextAlignmentLeft;

                [self.contentView addSubview:cellTitle];
                [cellTitle release];
            }
            default: break;
        }
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)touchDown: (id)sender {
    [delegate trashClickedNotify:sender];
}

-(void)valueChange:(id)sender {
    [delegate valueChangeNotify:sender];
}

- (void) InitCellTitleLable {
    cellTitle = (UILabel *)[self.contentView viewWithTag:TITLE_LABEL_TAG];
}

- (void) SetRowIndex: (int) _rowIndex {
    cellSwitch.tag = _rowIndex;
    cellButton.tag = _rowIndex;
}

- (void) SwitchOnOff: (BOOL) _switchTo {
    cellSwitch.on = _switchTo;

}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//- Set title of the Cell. ----------------------------------------------------------------------- ViTo Code ----//
- (void) SetCellTitle: (NSString*) _cellTitle {
    cellTitle.text = _cellTitle;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//- Deallocates the memory occupied by the receiver. --------------------------------------------- ViTo Code ----//
- (void)dealloc {
    // Delloc objects.
    //[self.cellMainImage release];
    //[self.cellTitle release];
    //[self.cellDataTime release];

    // Call base delloc
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```